# how to install themeforest-T5ELugiM-claue-clean-minimal-magento-2-theme in magneto 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, theme, configuration, installation, custom-theme

It shows Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme 'MGS Claue'.

Answer (score 0):

just got o you database search of Theme Table and make the following changes mention.

All themes should have type set to 0. Sometimes magento likes to change it to 1 (virtual theme).

follow below screenshot
[image]

**hope this helps**